# show() hide() checkbox : jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I want to show and hide a checkbox(sem_1_ma_english) depending upon the values of a Dropdown(course_english) list.

When I select a values from the DROPDOWN list, then the CHECKBOX should be displayed otherwise not.

Html structure:For Checkbox

```
<div class="form-row">
<label for="sem_1_ma_english">
   Semester I – Subjects for M. A. English
<span class="helptext"></span>
</label>
<label for="sem_1_ma_english-poetry">
<input id="sem_1_ma_english-poetry" class="" type="checkbox" checked="yes" value="Poetry" name="sem_1_ma_english[]">
 Poetry
</label>
<label for="sem_1_ma_english-drama">
<input id="sem_1_ma_english-drama" class="" type="checkbox" checked="yes" value="Drama"  name="sem_1_ma_english[]">
Drama
</label>
<label for="sem_1_ma_english-fiction">
<input id="sem_1_ma_english-fiction" class="" type="checkbox" checked="yes" value="Fiction" name="sem_1_ma_english[]">
Fiction
</label>
<label for="sem_1_ma_english-prose">
<input id="sem_1_ma_english-prose" class="" type="checkbox" checked="yes" value="Prose"  name="sem_1_ma_english[]">
Prose
</label>
</div>
```

So I have used the piece of code to solve the problem

```
$("#course_english").change(function() {
    if ($("#course_english").val() == "MA English") {
        $("#sem_1_ma_english").parent().show();
    } else {
        $("#sem_1_ma_english").parent().hide();
        $("#sem_1_ma_english").val('');
    }
});
```

But sadly it is not working.

Comment: Can we see the code for the dropdown list?

Comment: Could you make a fiddle containing both the JS and HTML parts of the code? It'd help coders fix it.

Comment: Also it seems you don't have an element with the id sem_1_ma_english

Comment: @mikeswright49 : Here is code for Drop down list               `<select id="course_english" class="" name="course_english">
<option value="">--Select One--</option>
<option value="MA English">MA English</option>
<option value="B. A. (Hons.) with Mass Communication">B.A. (Hons.) with Mass Communication</option>
<option value="M. A. (English)">M. A. (English)</option>
<option value="M. Phil.">M. Phil.</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 1):

For your issue check this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ujuxiy/1/edit

if this is your html:

```
<select id="course_english" class="" name="course_english"> 
    <option value="">--Select One--</option> 
    <option value="MA English">MA English</option> 
    <option value="B. A. (Hons.) with Mass Communication">B.A. (Hons.) with Mass Communication</option> 
    <option value="M. A. (English)">M. A. (English)</option> <option value="M. Phil.">M. Phil.</option> 
</select>


  <div class="form-row">
  <label for="sem_1_ma_english">
      Semester I – Subjects for M. A. English
      <span class="helptext"></span>
  </label>
  <label for="sem_1_ma_english-poetry">
      <input id="sem_1_ma_english-poetry" class="sem_1_ma_english" type="checkbox"     checked="yes"      value="Poetry" name="sem_1_ma_english[]">
Poetry
 </label>
 <label for="sem_1_ma_english-drama">
  <input id="sem_1_ma_english-drama" class="sem_1_ma_english" type="checkbox" checked="yes"     value="Drama"  name="sem_1_ma_english[]">
Drama
</label>
 <label for="sem_1_ma_english-fiction">
  <input id="sem_1_ma_english-fiction" class="sem_1_ma_english" 
   type="checkbox" checked="yes" value="Fiction" name="sem_1_ma_english[]">
  Fiction
 </label>
 <label for="sem_1_ma_english-prose">
 <input id="sem_1_ma_english-prose" class="sem_1_ma_english" type="checkbox" checked="yes"      value="Prose" name="sem_1_ma_english[]">
 Prose
</label></div>
```

then this should be your jquery for this:

```
 $(function(){
    $(".form-row").hide();
       $("#course_english").change(function() {
         if ($("#course_english").val() == "MA English") {
             $(".form-row").show();
         } else {
            $(".form-row").hide();
         }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one 
**HTML**

```
<div class="form-row">
<label for="sem_1_ma_english">
Semester I – Subjects for M. A. English
<span class="helptext"></span>
</label>
<label for="sem_1_ma_english-poetry">
<input id="sem_1_ma_english-poetry" class="sem_1_ma_english" type="checkbox" checked="yes"      value="Poetry" name="sem_1_ma_english[]">
Poetry
</label>
<label for="sem_1_ma_english-drama">
<input id="sem_1_ma_english-drama" class="sem_1_ma_english" type="checkbox" checked="yes"     value="Drama"  name="sem_1_ma_english[]">
Drama
</label>
<label for="sem_1_ma_english-fiction">
<input id="sem_1_ma_english-fiction" class="sem_1_ma_english" 
type="checkbox" checked="yes" value="Fiction" name="sem_1_ma_english[]">
Fiction
</label>
<label for="sem_1_ma_english-prose">
<input id="sem_1_ma_english-prose" class="sem_1_ma_english" type="checkbox" 
 checked="yes"      value="Prose"  
 name="sem_1_ma_english[]">
 Prose
</label>
```

ANd jQuery code should be like this

```
$("#course_english").change(function() {
   if ($("#course_english").val() == "MA English") {
       $(".sem_1_ma_english").parent().show();
   } else {
       $(".sem_1_ma_english").parent().hide();
       $(".sem_1_ma_english").val('');
   }
});
```

Try this one this is working for me , and work for you....

Comment: Check several things, did you put you jQuery code after $(document).readu() and did you use the exactly code as I had shown you because I had make some change in html and jQuery and if yes then please specify your question more, I need a code for dropdownlias how there are a values and how they appear....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the 'toggle()' method? I prefer this to alternating 'show' and 'hide'. This method works well with click events but I haven't tried it with selecting values.

e.g.

```
 $(".sem_1_ma_english").parent().show(); //Shows initially
      if ($("#course_english").val() == "MA English") {
        $(".sem_1_ma_english").parent().toggle();
      };    
    });
```